# listbox in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, listbox

I'm working on a C# windows forms application.I am using datagridview to list details from database. In one of my form i want datagridview given row to list its sub items. One row contain multiple sub items .

```
-------------------------
  Item name  -  Quantity-
-------------------------
   Fruit     -   10Kg   -
   Seeds     -   5kg    -
             -          -
-------------------------
```

Fruit sub item consist of Apple,Pineapple etc...

This above table is a datagridview. On clicking the Fruit cell , I want to display its sub in a LISTBOX on current cell bottom or in that current row. In datagridview column type i can'nt get any datagridviewlistbox column.

Comment: Do you want to put a listbox in a cell of the grid?! I'm afraid that's not possible! The option you have is a Master-Detail gridview, showing the detail of the fruits in sub-grid.

Comment: how to set Master detail in datagridview in c-sharp windows application

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should help you achieve what you are looking for.

Check out this MSDN article : - [How to: Create a Master/Detail Form Using Two Windows Forms DataGridView Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c12c1kx4.aspx)